# How to add fields in custom registration form, validate it and save to db?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation

Im using a WP theme with a custom registration form. I want to add two fields to it (for phone number and company name). What to add to the php file of the form and what to the function file of theme to validate the fields and save the values ​​in the database?

The structure of the theme is quite complex (at least according to my skills and knowledge).

This is the registration form: `register_form.php - https://pastebin.com/A5s4QPGw`. The theme has a core plugin that uses different Managers for different features of the theme. This is the manager responsible for registration: `RegisterManager.php - https://pastebin.com/buFfhFaU`.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: wordpress plugins may help you better. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-registration-form-builder-with-submission-manager/

Comment: I want to use theme registration form, not another one. Just want to add some fields to that form.